# Where do I place my "document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "";" Within my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, getelementbyid, countdowntimer

At the moment I am creating an on screen timer in javascript. This is the code for my timer:

```
var i = 30;

function startTimer() {
var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {

console.log(i);
i = i - 1;

if (i < 0) {

clearInterval(countdownTimer);

}

}, 1000);

}
```

I am just wondering where I should place my document.getElementById("time-remaining").innerHTML = "Time Remaining:" + i;

I am also wondering if the above document.getElementById is correct (will it be displayed as a onscreen timer or will it fail or something)?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = 30;
function startTimer() {
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(i);
        i = i - 1;
        if (i < 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            return; //This will prevent -1 to be written to html
        }
        document.getElementById("time-remaining").innerHTML = "Time Remaining:" + i;
    }, 1000);
}
startTimer();
```

Dont forget to call the function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/842/

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now! Just wondering: When I call the function the timer goes double the speed it should. Do I need to call the function?

Comment: Maybe you are calling the function twice. But anyway the timer is set to 1 second, so it will execute in a period of 1 second only. Check your code

Answer (score 0):

You can put the

```
document.getElementById("time-remaining").innerHTML = "Time Remaining:" + i;
```

After the `startTimer` function or really anywhere.

And yes the`document.getElementById` is correct, if your html id is the same one as in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I put it under the var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() { and it worked well.

Comment: Cool! Glad yo have helped.